# React/Redux: modified state is not updated in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my react native application using redux the reducers seems to working fine, but UI won't update on state modifications.

This is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  userId: 1,
  userName: "nobody",
  showIntroOnNextStart: true
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            let newState = {
                ...state,
                userId: state.userId + 1
            };
            console.log(newState);
            return newState;

    }
    return state;
}
```

It will exported and imported via:

```
import userProfile from './userProfile'

export { userProfile }
```

This is my connect method:

```
export default connect(state => ({
   state: state.userProfile
 }),
 (dispatch) => ({
   actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
 })
)(ApplicationContainer);
```

So the final state looks like this:

[image]

In render-method of my application component i pass the state to sub-components:

```
render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return ....lots of scenes...
            <Scene key="home" component={HomeScreen} title="Home" state={state} {...actions} />
```

In the specific scene-component i work with the state like this:

```
render(){
    const { state, decrement, increment } = this.props;

    return (
        <View {...this.props}  style={styles.container}>

            <Text>{state.userId}</Text>

            <Button onPress={increment}>Increment</Button>
        </View>
    );
}
```

The increment action works fine as expected, every console.log-Output shows a new state object with correct incremented values.

But the view will not updated.
In the reducer-function, the state works as expected and increments the userId on every call. But in the render-function the state objects values remains the same from the beginning.

What could be went wrong here?

### UPDATE

When i remove this Router-Stuff from react-native-router-flux, everything works fine. The state will be the same instance and will be updated. But as soon as encapsulating the component into a scene of the router, the state update will not happen

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the props you pass on the render function? If it doesn't log as often as an action occurs it may be that you have a shouldComponentUpdate function defined, which skips the update?

Comment: Just a comment; it is confusing when you are using **state** as a props variable. You should try to find another name that fits your design.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited time with Redux, the problem with not rendering is usually the reference for the object not changing. You need to do deep copy if you have a deep object. I personally like to use immutable.js for any state in react.

One other thing you can try to narrow down the problem is to call this.forceUpdate() on the component after you press Increment. If it updates the view, that will get you a step closer to figuring out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the state doesn't immediately update it, it only puts it in a pending status.

From my experience the reason it won't display the update because of a disconnect between the smart component that is actually updating the state and the dumb component that is displaying it. You should on most instances have your smart containers pass the application state to their components: in this instance your app component passing the incremented id to the scene. What I couldn't see right away is where your handleOnPress function is. Ideally, you'd want to pass both the state and the onPress function down to your scene, so that when they click it it calls the action from your app container, which will update the state, and trigger the re-render.

Hopefully this helps a bit, I didn't immediately see anything wrong with the code you presented here, but it might just have to do with the way you're connected these together.

Comment: When i remove this Router-Stuff from react-native-router-flux, everything works fine. The state will be the same instance and will be updated. But as soon as encapsulating the component into a scene of the router, the state update will not happen

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps using a navigator at some point? I've noticed that Navigator creates scenes once, and even if the data changes after that, it doesn't necessarily recreate the scenes after it's mounted even if the state updates. My temporary solution (before discarding navigator entirely) was to use this.forceUpdate(). It's not an ideal solution but gets the work done.

Comment: as far as i know the used redux-router-flux-component uses the new NavigatorExperimental

Comment: where to place this.forceUpdate()? In render method?

Comment: Yuo could try something like this:
<Button onPress={() => {this.props.increment(); this.forceUpdate();} }>Increment</Button>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Tell me the result...

case 'INCREMENT':
            let newState = Object.assign(
                {},
                ...state,
                userId: state.userId + 1
            );
            console.log(newState);
            return newState;

Comment: this gives an Syntax Error: let newState = Object.assign( {}, ...state, userId: state.userId + 1 );

Comment: ah, it must be: let newState = Object.assign( {}, ...state, {userId: state.userId + 1} );

but it doesnt help. same behaviour as bevore

Comment: Hmm, instead of using const in your specific scene component. Have u tried using let? Maybe it wont be mutated because of 'const'

Comment: When i remove this Router-Stuff from react-native-router-flux, everything works fine. The state will be the same instance and will be updated. But as soon as encapsulating the component into a scene of the router, the state update will not happen

Comment: @adrianhartanto `const` only prevents reassignment

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to redux store, map state to props in your scene components